# Update value from previous row value

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have following data:

```
 Item daytime               sub_hours  ch_size
 -------------------------------------------------------
 t23  18-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        56.8
 t23  18-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5  
 t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
 t24  18-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5           
 t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0          45.4
 t23  19-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        70.2
 t23  19-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5  
 t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
 t24  19-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5           
 t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.2
```

I'd like to get this result:

```
 Item daytime               sub_hours  ch_size
 -------------------------------------------------------
 t23  18-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        56.8
 t23  18-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5        56.8
 t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
 t24  18-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5        40.8   
 t24  18-Aug-17 02:30:00    0          45.4
 t23  19-Aug-17 03:30:00    0.5        70.2
 t23  19-Aug-17 04:00:00    0.5        70.2
 t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.5        40.8
 t24  19-Aug-17 04:40:00    0.5        40.8   
 t24  19-Aug-17 02:30:00    0.2
```

I need to update ch_size column set it to previous value where
ch_size is null and sub_hours = 0.5:

here is code I use:

```
update day_status a set ch_size = 
( select prev_choke from
  (
     select LAG(ch_size) OVER (order by item, daytime) as prev_choke
     from day_status  
     where trunc(daytime) between to_date('1 Aug 2017') and to_date('31 Aug 2017')
   ) b where a.item = b.item and a.daytime=b.daytime
 )
```

I've haven't tested this code, do you think it's correct and achieve result I want?

thanks,
S

Comment: You are missing `... WHERE ch_size IS NULL AND sub_hours = 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LAG](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions) function. It will give you the value of the previous row.

```
SELECT empno,
       ename,
       job,
       sal,
       LAG(sal, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY sal) AS sal_prev,
       sal - LAG(sal, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY sal) AS sal_diff
FROM   emp;
```

---

```
     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL   SAL_PREV   SAL_DIFF
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            800          0        800
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950        800        150
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100        950        150
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250       1100        150
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250       1250          0
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300       1250         50
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500       1300        200
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600       1500        100
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450       1600        850
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850       2450        400
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975       2850        125
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000       2975         25
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000       3000          0
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000       3000       2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `item` and `daytime` are primary key

```
UPDATE day_status a 
SET a.ch_size = 
( 
  SELECT LAG(ch_size) OVER (ORDER BY item, daytime) as prev_choke
  FROM day_status b
  WHERE a.item = b.item AND a.daytime=b.daytime
) 
WHERE a.ch_size IS NULL AND a.sub_hours = 0.5
```

Comment: @JoeGreen does it answer your query?

Comment: to Radim Bača: tested your code, it sets for some reason a.ch_size to null, not sure why.

Comment: @JoeGreen interesting, it always does?

Comment: to Radim Bača:  yes, and it doesn't make sense as there is previous value.